# How many brothers does Lady Farnese have?

Tags: berserk

It's mentioned earlier on that she was her father's only legitimate child, but then it's shown in chapter 252 that she has 3 more brothers, not including Serpico.

Could anyone clear that up, please?

Note: if it's explained beyond chapter 252, please explicitly mark it with a spoiler warning.

Comment: I checked the Wikia and it seems that's it's true she has 3 brothers and a half-brother. Considering that I don't follow the series, it could be just a lie for a purpose of plot-device. Also, providing a reference to the "she was he father's only legitimate child" would be better to make this question complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Farnese has

> **3 brothers** and **1 half-brother**.

In **Vol. 14 Chapter 96**,

> [Serpico](http://berserk.wikia.com/wiki/Serpico#Manga), his half-brother, was first introduced. His relation to Farnese, however, was only revealed on **Vol. 22 Chapter 185**. [image]

In **Vol. 29 Chapter 251**,

> [Magnifico](http://berserk.wikia.com/wiki/Magnifico), his brother, was first shown arguing with their father, and he would later on join her and Guts' Travelling Party in their journey to Elfheim: [image]

In **Vol. 29 Chapter 255**,

> his other brothers, [Giorgio and Poliziano](http://berserk.wikia.com/wiki/Minor_Characters#Giorgio), was first revealed, and this is the only appearance they have made so far: [image]

Comment: This answer is so creative!  Great job!